# If the Earth is placed between three spinning black holes, Will time on Earth slow down? Will we live longer?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, reference-frames, time-dilation, observers

Just randomly thought of placing the Earth equidistant from 3 spinning black holes. Will time on the Earth slow down? Will we age slower? Assuming that the Earth is not past the event horizon yet the black holes are very close to the Earth.

Comment: Sounds tricky. ;) Why do you want 3 black holes? How do you propose to stop them from colliding with each other?

Comment: @PM2Ring I haven't really thought of the details, just thought I'd ask in the forum after thingking of it (laughs in cold sweat)

Comment: Orbits get really complicated around black holes. Unlike in Newtonian gravity, with its elliptical orbits, there's generally no simple equation for a body orbiting a static black hole (apart from a perfect circular orbit for a small body). Calculating the orbits of 3 spinning BHs would take *serious* computing power. And the orbits would constantly change, due to the massive amount of energy radiated away as gravitational waves.

Comment: @PM2RingI see, thank you for your response. I thought the black holes could just orbit around their shared centre of gravity in the centre

Comment: Fair enough. But no, that won't work. But if you had one large BH with a lot of spin, and we were in orbit around it, sure we could get some time dilation. But what's the point? What benefit is there in living twice as long if every clock on the planet is also ticking twice as slowly?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, there is no point dilating time if the amount of time we experienced is the same without time dilation

Comment: "Age slower" *compared to which observer*? The whole point of relativity is that notions of time and space are *relative*, and statements like "time passes slower" only make sense with explicitly specified reference frames.

Answer (score 3):

This structure would be trivially unstable. I.e. any little deviation from the balance state would cause a yet more unbalanced state. The likely result will be two black holes orbiting each other closely, a third black hole orbiting them from more far away. The Earth would orbit yet more closely one of the black holes or it would be ejected from the system. Possibly also the third black hole would be ejected.

Time on the Earth would slow down. It is because the gravitational time dilatation is determined by $T^{00}$ in the [Stress-Energy Tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#/media/File:StressEnergyTensor_contravariant.svg). (The red square top left.) This is a scalar. If you have 3 equidistant masses, it simply adds together.

We would not feel that, because all of our internal chemistry and all the chemical/physical processes on the Earth would slow down similarly. The only what we would see, stellar processes would seem for us more fast (and all the spectra would get a blueshift).

Comment: Thank you for your response